# Vivagraph. Изображение двигается в обратном направлении движении мышки по оси Y

Tags: javascript, canvas, layout, webgl, render

В поисках библиотеки, которая будет хорошо работать при высоких нагрузках и при этом создавать нормальные графы, наткнулся на Vivagraph.js.

Решил протестировать функционал (использую webgl renderer, svg грузит DOM сильно), добавил 100 узлов с изображениями и соединениями и всё бы хорошо, только выбирая узел и двигая им, изображение двигается в противоположную сторону движения мыши.  Изображения расположены зеркально своим крайним точкам, где они должны быть. Как решить вопрос, я без понятия, поковырялся в либе, пока толку мало.

```
    function onLoad() {
    // randomizer to get random position for nodes
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    // instance of VivaGraph
    var graph = Viva.Graph.graph(),
        graphics = Viva.Graph.View.webglGraphics(),
        layout = Viva.Graph.Layout.constant(graph),
        nodePositions = [],
        nodeSize = 10,
        renderer = Viva.Graph.View.renderer(graph, {
            layout: layout, // use our custom 'constant' layout
            graphics: graphics
        }),
        i;

    // list of images
    var list = {
        '0': '../Resources/man.png',
        '1': '../Resources/organ.png',
        '2': '../Resources/woman.png',
        '3': '../Resources/woman_pep.png',
        '4': '../Resources/person.png',
        '5': '../Resources/person_pep.png',
        '6': '../Resources/organ_ps.png',
        '7': '../Resources/organ_inactive.png',
        '8': '../Resources/main_bank.png',
        '9': '../Resources/addition_bank.png'
    };

    // amount of nodes and edges
    var amount = 100;

    // add nodes
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        nodePositions[i] = {x: getRandomInt(0, 1200), y: getRandomInt(0, 600)};
        graph.addNode(i, nodePositions[i]);
        graph.addLink(0, i);
    }

    // set custom node placement callback for layout.
    // if you don't do this, constant layout performs random positioning.
    // use built-in WebGL program for images
    graphics.setNodeProgram(Viva.Graph.View.webglImageNodeProgram());

    // add random image per node
    graphics.node(function(node) {
        ui = Viva.Graph.View.webglImage(nodeSize, list[node.id % 10]);
        return ui;
    });

    // place node position
    layout.placeNode(function(node) {
        return nodePositions[node.id];
    });

    renderer.run();

    setTimeout(renderer.rerender, 50);
}
```

Вот исходник так сказать.  Буду благодарен, за полезный совет.

Answer (score 0):

Я не являюсь знатоком этой библиотеки, но тут скорее всего надо сделать так, чтобы координаты мыши были в том пространстве в котором у вас рисуется график (линейное преобразование координат мыши в пространство графика), тогда подобного некорректного поведения, связанного с движением изображения не будет.

Конкретнее - координаты мыши находятся в пространстве где начало координат это левый верхний угол, а график рисуется с учётом начала координат в левом нижнем угле, поэтому при движении мыши вниз `y` координата мыши возрастает в своём пространстве, а это означает убывание в пространстве графика, отсюда и такой эффект.

Тоесть всё, что вам необходимо сделать, это преобразовать `y` координату мыши -

`mouse.y = height - mouse.y`

где `height` - высота области в котором рисуется график

Comment: Спасибо, я вчера нашел в чем проблема, так что всё ок.